# solve a complex integral

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I stumbled on this integral, the problem says to solve it with contour integration. Any insights on how to solve this in function of $n$?

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}(\theta)d\theta
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}.$$
Set $z=e^{i\theta}$ and compute the residue in the origin of $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{z+1/z}{2}\right)^{2n}.$